# is there anyway to run a function inside a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run a function (that will give a random number) and display that in a string (btw this is part of a discord bot) and I'm wondering how I could do that

```
    em = discord.Embed(title = "You Earned rndm",
    color = discord.Color(value = 0x2ecc71))
```

'rndm' is my function and I'm wondering if there is a way for it to display the number that the function gives instead of text?

Comment: Use `title = f"You Earned {rndm()}"`

Comment: [Using an f-string should be all you need to do for this](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do the below

```
string = "text you want " + str(rndm()) + "more text"
```

Or

```
string = f"text you want {str(rndm())} and more text"
```

If your function returns a string you don't need the str() but it sounds like it returns an int